# Autosave in Atom doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: atom-editor, autosave

I am using Atom and I'm trying to get autosave to work. It's in the packages, enabled, and has the check box enabled.

Here is some relevant info:

- I'm running on Windows 10
- My code is not local, it's ssh'd in from a vm

For what it's worth I tried to map Ctrl-Shift-S to save all and that won't work either.  I'll post another question about hotkeys.

Comment: I am running on Mac and have the same issue